# How to determine the file path in XML configuration

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate, messagebroker, xml-configuration

I am migrating to use new RabbitMQ(RMQ) console. The new RabbitMQ console required to enable the SSL connection from my logic by adding the certificate path. Anyone know how to add/enable the 'file path' like "C:\User... " into XML configuration format?. I did something like this D:\Apps\Certificate..., the logic able to read the path but not able to create a connection to the destination. Kindly assist :) Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain the problem in more detail and also the steps you tried.

Comment: Hi Sree Harsha Nellore , basically my question is how to determine or how to write the file path like C:\Users\... in the XML Configuration file format. As the one that I did, the code logic able to read the path but there are no process after that.